# Movie about people who take some kind of drug and hear a transmission from a numbers station

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror

I only watched a small part of this movie. I think the premise of this movie is that a group of characters is under the influence of some kind of drug.

One scene I watched involved one of the characters having seizures and foaming at the mouth. I think that character may or may not have died shortly afterwards.

I also remember a scene where the characters hear a transmission that sounds almost exactly like this one from the "Swedish Rhapsody" Numbers Station.

Comment: *Through a Scanner Darkly*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like ***[Banshee Chapter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2011276/?ref_=tt_urv)*** (2013).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banshee_Chapter):

> *Banshee Chapter* (sometimes referred to as *The Banshee Chapter*) is a 2013 American horror film and the directorial debut of Blair Erickson. The film had its first screening at the Fantasy Filmfest on August 22, 2013 and released on video on demand on December 12 of the same year. Banshee Chapter stars Katia Winter as a journalist who is trying to discover what happened to a missing friend. The film is loosely based on the H. P. Lovecraft short story "From Beyond".

> The movie begins with stock footage of President Clinton and other people announcing the existence of the government experiment Project MKUltra. The scene then cuts away to camera footage of James Hirsch (Michael McMillian), a young man investigating Project MKUltra. **With a friend filming him, James takes the drug used in the experiments, dimethyltryptamine-19 (DMT-19). Soon, bizarre music and voices begin to broadcast from a nearby radio and James becomes extremely anxious, announcing that something is coming towards the house and that it wants to "wear them".** A large, shadowy figure rushes by the window and the camera's footage cuts in and out, ultimately ending with a shot of James with all-black eyes and a disfigured face.
>
> **The movie then shifts to Anne (Katia Winter) a reporter who attended college with James. She is concerned over his disappearance, as James's friend also mysteriously disappeared a few days after he was questioned by the police.** Anne investigates James's house and discovers a betamax cassette that contains footage of the MKUltra experiments as well as a book of notes about the project. Curious about some of the things found in the house — particularly some information about radio waves — **Anne goes to a local expert and discovers that the bizarre radio broadcast heard by James is a phantom radio station, which can only be tuned into in the desert, at a certain time of night.** Anne drives out into the desert after dark and is able to pick up the broadcast, but flees when a monstrous form appears from the darkness.

You can watch the aforementioned character, James, listening to the radio broadcast at the 5:59 mark in the video below. Two other characters -- Anne and the 'local expert' -- listen to the same broadcast and discuss numbers stations shortly after the 14:24 mark.